# Remove horizontal line in table

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jframe

I have a `JTable` in a frame. I want to to remove horizontal (row) lines in the table, just the name of a column that has a horizontal line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`JTable#setShowHorizontalLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowHorizontalLines%28boolean%29) to `false`

You may also want to take a look at [`JTable#setShowGrid`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowGrid%28boolean%29) as well